# Xamarin iOS: Am I understand correctly with NSTimer which running on RunLoop

Tags: ios, xamarin, nstimer

Currently I want to schedule the app to download at certain interval so I used a code below.

```
 downloadTimer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(30, DownloadEntityFromServer);

NSRunLoop.Current.AddTimer(downloadTimer, NSRunLoopMode.Default);
```

This code was added in the FinishLaunching function, there when the application launched the timer added to the run loop.

I understand that the application in background will not run until the application return to foreground. Before background the time remaining was 20sec before it execute the code. Later when the application back to foreground, will the timer continue to time the remaining 20sec.

Is this the same behaviour if app go from suspended state to foreground.

Comment: No. The timer will not be stop or pause when the application suspended.

Comment: What if the timer passed the specified time interval while the app was suspended and the app return back to foreground. Does that get fired straightaway?